# How is the amplitude of an output signal of a binary input determined using a constellation pattern?

Tags: binary, amplitude

I understand using the pattern to find the output line single phase but how is the amplitude determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how is the amplitude determined?

By the length of the line from the origin to each constellation point: -

[image]

The above image has equal amplitudes for all four binary values hence they sit on the circumference of a circle.

The one below has 8 binary values and the amplitude of the inner four is smaller than the outer four.

[image]

Comment: Is this true as well for a binary signal?

Comment: It usually is but needn’t be theoretically. BPSK (binary phase shift keying) is a good example of two points having equal amplitude but a phase angle of 180 degrees between the two signals.

Comment: So first image is 1v. 5v, 0v range   second image would be 1v, 0.75v ,0.5v 0v range?

Comment: I don’t know how you arrived at those numbers frankly. In the 1st diagram, all amplitudes are the same because all four binary vales are represented on one circle having a constant radius.

Comment: If you are wondering how each constellation point is ascribed a binary value then that is completely arbitrary. The example binary values in my pictures are purely examples and need not be like that.